# on the truth quest vs in the quest for truth

Tags: prepositions, american-english

What is the difference in meaning between:
on the truth quest vs in the quest for truth
or:
on the happiness quest vs in the quest for the happiness
Examples https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quest:
Nothing will stop them in their quest for truth.
Examples on the Twitter https://twitter.com/joshsimona/status/1129043253574230021:
...most people are not on the truth quest, most people are on the happiness quest

Comment: *Syntactically*, a *truth quest* is an attributive noun (adjective) followed by a noun. But a *quest for truth* is a noun followed by a prepositional phrase.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"The quest for [anything]" is an established phrase. "The [anything] quest" is not, and without context it might be momentarily confusing.

Otherwise there is no difference.